# How does this array of objects initialize each object's member variable?

Tags: c++, initialization

```
#include <cstudio>

struct Food {
   char recipe[128];
};

void print_food(Food* food_ptr) {
   printf("Recipe: %s\n", food_ptr->recipe);
}

int main() {
   Food menu[] = {"Burn it", "Drop it", "USe too much salt"};
   print_food(menu);
}
```

How are the Food objects initialized in the `menu` array? It doesn't appear to invoke any constructors, not that there are even any defined anyway.

Comment: It's called [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: Each element is [copy initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from the corresponding value in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you should know, that constructors get implicitly written if they haven't been written explicitly.

As super already mentioned, your recipe is [aggregate initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).